# OpenWeatherMap get average temperature on day

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

Using the openweathermap api how can I get the average temperature on a certain day using javascript. I know I am limited with only getting with in the next 5 days. I have been looking and could not find a way to do it and have seen nobody else do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the api `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}`. Please refer [here](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5) for more details.

You can search weather forecast for 5 days with data every 3 hours by city name. All weather data can be obtained in JSON and XML formats.

https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

> **API call:**
>
> `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}`
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> q city name and country code divided by comma, use ISO 3166 country
> codes
>
> **Examples of API calls:**
>
> api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml

Comment: I understand the API but the issue is it gives me the next 5 days in 3 hours blocks, and I am having issues finding a way to get the temperature on a certain day

Comment: Could you be more specific. Is the issue with parsing data?

Comment: HamptonM is quite clear... API gives you 8 blocks of info per day (every 3 hours) and he wants just 1 with the average for the full day.

Comment: @der_chirurg i will be honest, I do not remember in the slightest. This project was over two years ago and through a series of unfortunate data corruptions has been wiped off the face of the earth. I have marked this as the answer as it seems to answer the question

Comment: to be honest, I'm here with the same issue/scenario; however, the team and I decided that it is aesthetically wrong to assume the average of that 8 blocks of data will represent the day's temperature. So, the best thing to do is displaying the "High" and "Low" of the day ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

if you use free mode, you can use API this > [https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=%7Blat%7D&lon=%7Blon%7D&exclude=%7Bpart%7D&appid=%7BAPI) key}

for 'exclude' the value is 'current'

and you can find in result 'daily'

like below, data in daily only 7 day if you use free mode[image]

{"dt":1616238000,"temp":301.64,"feels_like":305.49,"pressure":1006,"humidity":72,"dew_point":296.11,"uvi":0.17,"clouds":97,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":1.94,"wind_deg":25,"wind_gust":4.14,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.39}],"**daily**":[{"dt":1616043600,"sunrise":1616023825,"sunset":1616067395,"temp":{"day":305.68,"min":296.48,"max":305.68,"night":298.13,"eve":301.4,"morn":296.48},"feels_like":{"day":309.22,"night":302.32,"eve":306.11,"morn":300.23},"pressure":1010,"humidity":55,"dew_point":295.34,"wind_speed":1.88,"wind_deg":2,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":71,"pop":0.58,"rain":1.88,"uvi":14.19},{"dt":1616130000,"sunrise":1616110201,"sunset":1616153783,"temp":{"day":305.38,"min":296.44,"max":305.62,"night":298.19,"eve":301.52,"morn":296.44},"feels_like":{"day":308.32,"night":302.18,"eve":306.01,"morn":300.25},"pressure":1010,"humidity":54,"dew_point":294.93,"wind_speed":2.3,"wind_deg":347,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":5,"pop":0.94,"rain":4.71,"uvi":13.78},{"dt":1616216400,"sunrise":1616196576,"sunset":1616240170,"temp":{"day":305.82,"min":296.51,"max":306.34,"night":298.41,"eve":301.64,"morn":296.51},"feels_like":{"day":308.58,"night":302.5,"eve":305.49,"morn":300.44},"pressure":1009,"humidity":51,"dew_point":294.26,"wind_speed":2.17,"wind_deg":349,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":93,"pop":0.4,"rain":0.23,"uvi":13.37},{"dt":1616302800,"sunrise":1616282952,"sunset":1616326557,"temp":{"day":305.56,"min":297.1,"max":305.56,"night":298.4,"eve":299.56,"morn":297.1},"feels_like":{"day":308.74,"night":303.18,"eve":304.47,"morn":300.75},"pressure":1009,"humidity":55,"dew_point":295.3,"wind_speed":2.31,"wind_deg":339,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":88,"pop":0.48,"rain":1.85,"uvi":13.47},{"dt":1616389200,"sunrise":1616369327,"sunset":1616412945,"temp":{"day":306.08,"min":296.6,"max":306.08,"night":298.56,"eve":299.63,"morn":296.6},"feels_like":{"day":309.2,"night":303.14,"eve":304.4,"morn":300.19},"pressure":1010,"humidity":52,"dew_point":294.84,"wind_speed":2.07,"wind_deg":13,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":98,"pop":0.67,"rain":3.8,"uvi":14},{"dt":1616475600,"sunrise":1616455702,"sunset":1616499332,"temp":{"day":307.01,"min":296.67,"max":307.01,"night":298.42,"eve":299.71,"morn":296.79},"feels_like":{"day":310.15,"night":303.02,"eve":304.13,"morn":300.55},"pressure":1009,"humidity":48,"dew_point":294.56,"wind_speed":1.7,"wind_deg":21,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":87,"pop":0.94,"rain":11.17,"uvi":14},{"dt":1616562000,"sunrise":1616542078,"sunset":1616585719,"temp":{"day":303.09,"min":297.35,"max":304.92,"night":298.34,"eve":299.46,"morn":297.35},"feels_like":{"day":307.61,"night":303.41,"eve":303.92,"morn":301.36},"pressure":1008,"humidity":71,"dew_point":297.08,"wind_speed":1.94,"wind_deg":348,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":94,"pop":1,"rain":14.31,"uvi":14},{"dt":1616648400,"sunrise":1616628453,"sunset":1616672106,"temp":{"day":305.73,"min":296.37,"max":305.73,"night":298.53,"eve":299.48,"morn":296.37},"feels_like":{"day":309.24,"night":302.82,"eve":304.03,"morn":300.08},"pressure":1008,"humidity":55,"dew_point":295.37,"wind_speed":1.96,"wind_deg":49,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":49,"pop":1,"rain":17.92,"uvi":14}]}